# Popularity of jQuery Mobile C-grade browsers

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

JQM leaves C-grades usable, not appealing to look at. Does the market share of C-grade browsers justify making a whole new stylesheet for them? Are there any credible statistics on their popularity?

Comment: Blackberry 4.x, Windows Mobile and older smartphone platforms (that don’t support media queries)? I doubt that.

Comment: @Smamatti A full list can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/. My question is whether or not they are common enough to worry about. They are usable in either case, but is it a waste of time to build a solid appearance for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry 4.x - You can get the ans here-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868567/what-market-share-do-each-of-the-blackberry-models-have
as u can see for 4.x its too less to worry about and its diminishing everyday.

Windows Mobile - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile#Market_share 
As read from the article, the market share is very less and no major manufacturer supports. so gone case.

All older smartphone platforms and featurephones – As the link says all browsers/smartphones not supporting CSS3 media queries will experience C class experience. Here is a link to give u an idea of browsers. http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html#t021

And correspondingly for those os' or browsers the market share is way low to consider making a separate style sheet for them without media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here are metrics from a site I work on from Jan 2012 to March 22nd for mobile. Out of MANY thousands of visits:

```
64.49% Safari (iOS)
26.01% Android
2.95%  Chrome
2.56%  Mozilla Compatible Agent
2.42%  Firefox
1.03%  Internet Explorer
```

Keep in mind that market share of handsets does not exactly translate to actual web usage.  A lot of people still have feature phones and other C-Grade devices.  However, that's pretty irrelevant because the experience of surfing the web on those things SUCKS.  The users all know it and thus they do not use it for surfing the web.  I think it's noble that jQuery Mobile even tried to support them, but they really didn't have to because none (statistically speaking) of those people are surfing the web on their crappy little old devices.